# Commutator of an operator with its Hermitian adjoint in linear quantum systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, noise

I have a commutator of a single-mode photon field operator $\alpha$ with its Hermitian adjoint $\alpha^{\dagger}$.

[$\alpha$, $\alpha^{\dagger}$]

When this commutator gives a negative value, $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{\dagger}$ must be creation and annihilation operator, respectively. Does anyone know why? Apparently this can be explained from the definition of commutator.

The topic involved here is the commutator bracket conservation in quantum mechanical linear circuit.

Comment: You need to clarify your question: commutators do not give negative values, they give another operator.

Comment: Surely, the OP means a negative multiple of the identity operator.

Answer (score 2):

If the commutator is a negative number, we can always rescale the operators to have $[\alpha, \alpha^\dagger] = -1$. In that case, consider the operator $N = \alpha^\dagger \alpha$ which is Hermitian. By the properties of the commutator
\begin{align}
[N, \alpha] &= [\alpha^\dagger, \alpha] \alpha = \alpha \\
[N, \alpha^\dagger] &= \alpha^\dagger [\alpha, \alpha^\dagger] -\alpha^\dagger
\end{align}
now follows. This shows that starting from any eigenstate of $N$, acting with $\alpha$ ($\alpha^\dagger$) will raise (lower) its eigenvalue by 1. Therefore $\alpha$ and $\alpha^\dagger$ are creation and annihilation operators in a particular sense. They create and destroy quanta that are counted by the abstract operator $N$. What those mean physically depends on the application. But often (in systems based on oscillators), $N$ is proportional to the energy.

Comment: Commutators don’t give numbers, they give another operator *viz* $[L_x,L_y]=i\hbar L_z$.  Moreover, why not rescale $\alpha^\dagger$ to $-\alpha^\dagger$ to make any negative sign disappear?